# Not able to display a Rails graph using chartkick.js and Mysql - Giving timezone problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I am getting following error while trying to display a simple chartkick graph based on [https://richonrails.com/articles/charting-with-chartkick] online tutorial.

This is the error that I get when I try to hit the page that displays the chart in `Rails 4` application. It looks like I am missing Timezone support in `MySQL` but not sure how to install one. I am located in `US EST` timezone. How can I fix this issue?

**Gems Installed:**

```
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'active_median'
```

**Error Log:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Be sure to install time zone support - https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql):
    3:   <!-- Line Chart - Single Series -->
    4:   <div class="col-xs-6">
    5:     <h3>Visits By Day</h3>
    6:     <%= line_chart @visits.group_by_day(:visited_at, format: "%B %d, %Y").count, discrete: true %>
    7:   </div>
    8:
    9: </div>
  app/views/charts/show.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_charts_show_html_erb__137374658_98254572'
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">

  <!-- Line Chart - Single Series -->
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h3>Visits By Day</h3>
    <%= line_chart @visits.group_by_day(:visited_at, format: "%B %d, %Y").count, discrete: true %>
  </div>

</div>
```

**charts_controller.rb**

```
class ChartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @visits = Visit.all
  end
end
```

I already loaded some data from sample insert statements that came with the installation into MySQL timezone tables. Not sure what else I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

**It works for me.**

```
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <h3>Visits By Day</h3>
    <%= line_chart @visits.group(:visited_at).count, discrete: true %>
  </div>
```

**With MySQL database:**

```
insert into visits values(1,'Mexico',24,'2012-12-31','2012-12-31 11:30:45','2012-12-31 11:30:45');
```

***Date Format:*** '2012-12-31'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's already a help portion done up for you: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#for-mysql

Have you tried that resource? Did it work for you?

You should probably read up on the TimeZone portion of MySQL as well to help ground you on the issue and configuring your database properly: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

It also looks like MySQL comes with a time_zone table. Checkout @ankane's gist on getting MySQL support with TimeZone's: https://gist.github.com/ankane/1d6b0022173186accbf0